# How can I disable my App Profile Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am using Facebook Connect on an external website. I don't want to show an App Profile Page on Facebook for this app. The main reason is because I have a Fan Page of the same name on Facebook and I am trying to get "Likes" for the Fan Page.

But when you search for the Fan Page by name both the App Profile Page and the Fan Page show up in the search results. And there would be nothing of use to show on the App Profile Page since all I am using it for is Facebook Connect.

Is there a setting in the app setting to not show the profile page? Or better yet, to use the Fan Page as the app profile page?

Answer (score 1):

There currently doesn't exist a way to disable your App Profile Page or associate your app to a Facebook Page. We are planning to enable this soon after f8.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I hated this… so I tossed up a super simple redirect app. Toss this up as your default tab for the application and put the link to the page.

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=127885633976737

Also let me know if there's an error. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate app pages to regular fan pages now (go to your app page for instructions). App pages will be disabled by February.

> Removing App Profile Pages By February 1, 2012, we are removing App
>   Profile Pages. You can migrate Likes and the Vanity URL of this Page
>   to an existing Facebook Page with the same name and of Product/App
>   category.
>
> Click here to migrate to an existing Facebook Page

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. We ended up asking all of our fans to move over to become fans of our application page and then deleted our fan page.  The only thing you can do is set your app in sandbox mode but then obviously nobody except developers can access it.

Comment: They provide this functionality today and deprecating Application Profile pages in February. Visit your app page as application admin for instructions